# Load image file, add drop shadow, save file

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

I'm trying to do the following (in WPF):

1. Load an image (a .png file with a transparent background big enough
   to contain a drop shadow).
2. Apply a drop shadow effect.
3. Save the modified bitmap as a new file.

Here's what I've tried:

```
// Source and target image files
string srcImageFile = @"D:\foo.png";
string targetImageFile = @"D:\foo_shadow.png";

// Load source image
Uri uri = new Uri (srcImageFile);
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage (uri);

// Add drop shadow
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = bi;
DropShadowEffect dse = new DropShadowEffect();
dse.Direction = 225;
dse.Color = Color.FromArgb (255, 182, 194, 203);
dse.ShadowDepth = 10;
dse.BlurRadius = 14;
img.Effect = dse;

// Save modified image
BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add (BitmapFrame.Create (bi));
using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite (targetImageFile)) {
    encoder.Save (outputStream);
}
```

The generated target file contains the same image as the source file. Clearly I need to get at the modified bitmap before saving the target file. A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this line is not correct: `encoder.Frames.Add (BitmapFrame.Create (bi));` You should use the the image in the `img` variable to get stored. What this does is stores the original image (`bi`).

Comment: You may render the Image control into a RenderTargetBitmap and save that to file. No idea though how the drop shadow effect looks like on an Image control that shows an image with transparent background.

Comment: A nudge in the right direction: don't use wpf for editing images and saving them...

Comment: @ppeterka66 (and Clemens) I modified my save logic to retrieve (what I assume to be) the shadow-adorned image by creating a RenderTargetBitmap of the same dimensions as the image and rendering the image into it.  The generated image is now blank.  Either my drop shadow code is incorrect or the RenderTargetBitmap has bad bits, or both.

Comment: @StefanDenchev Can you suggest a GDI+ way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Answered by Pete O'Hanlon at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/651423/Load-image-file-add-drop-shadow-save-file).